# How to skip reading something in fscanf

Tags: c

If I have the following text file:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 YEAH

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 YEAH

I have to following code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int arr[5][10];

FILE* foo; 
foo = fopen("help.txt", "r");

int i, j;
int temp; 

while (i<5 && (fscanf(foo, "%d", &temp)) !=EOF ){   
    arr[i][0]= temp;

    for (j=1; j<10; j++){

        fscanf(foo, "%d", &temp);
            arr[i][j]=temp;

    }
    i++;
}


for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
fclose(foo);
}
```

...and it works perfectly fine when the text file has just numbers but when I add the characters "Yeah" to the text file, the code goes crazy. How do I include them? Please explain simply as I am still very new to this. Would I used fscanf(foo, %d%*c, &temp);??? Also how would I handle the new line statement if there is one?

Thank you very much

Edit:
the e input I provided initially was

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20.

Here everything is printed out correctly. When adding the word yeah to the text file after 10 the all the other numbers are 10 as well. Essentially it does not contain 11 12... to 20. and prints out: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

Comment: What do you mean by "the code goes crazy"?  Does your program crash?  If so, do you know which line this happens on?  Do you get unexpected output?  If so, what input did you provide, what output did you expect and what output did you receive?

Comment: format specifier of fscanf is %d. when it trying to read string it gets crash

Comment: @user2388958 Can you provide any clarifications by editing your question please?  It'll be very hard for people to understand the question if they have to piece it together from several posts

Comment: Okay, I edited the question. sorry for being unclear :(

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer now

Answer (score 1):

It is always easier to process data like this one line at a time, rather than one "token" at a time directly against the file.

Reading in a whole line with `fgets()` into a suitably big buffer, gives you the opportunity to take your time and go back and forth in the parsing, since it's all just bytes in memory at that point and you no longer risk confusion due to the file having a current position which is incremented as you read.

Your example conversion doesn't work, since you need something like "n numbers followed by something that is not a number, then end of line" which I don't think can be expressed as a single simple `fscanf()` conversion string.

Much easier to read in the whole line, then look at it token by token "by hand". See, for instance `strtok()` which is kind of dangerous in general but should be fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int e;
while (i<5 && (e = fscanf(foo, "%d", &temp)) !=EOF ){
    if(e==0) {
        fscanf(foo, "%*[^0-9]"); // this will skip the non numeric chars
        continue;
    }
    arr[i][0]= temp;
```

and

```
for (j=1; j<10; j++){
    e = fscanf(foo, "%d", &temp);
    if (e==EOF) break;
    else if (e==0) {
        fscanf(foo, "%*[^0-9]"); continue;
    }
    arr[i][j]=temp;
```

Comment: Oh that's amazing. Now let's say I want to do the opposite and ignore the numbers, is there a similar statement?

Comment: for the oppposite, Please ask a new question and give an example code as you did in this question

Comment: Also how would it be different if the text statement was before the numbers. ie. yeah 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: I just meant a similar statement for  "%*[^0-9]" As in "%*[^A-Z]" or something?

Comment: concerning the `yeah 1 2 3 4 5` it's taken account in the code of the answer (code after update)

Comment: Actually what does  "%*[^0-9]" even mean? Sorry

Comment: "%*[0-9]" this mean catch all charachters and stop when find a number. using * means that the catched chars are not saved

Comment: to skeep numbers you can use `"%*[0-9]"`.

Comment: and to catch the strings without numbers into `char buf[100];` you can use the following `fscanf(foo, "%[^0-9]", buf);` you can see that the asterisk (*) is removed here because we are going to save the catched chars